# how do I get 0.0.0.0 to resolve to localhost when browsing a url that contains 0.0.0.0?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ip-address, localhost

Doing some node development on windows. Node programs like to kick out URLs that look like `http://0.0.0.0:8080`. In Linux (iirc) pasting that url into the browser will be successful. But in Windows, it's a 404. I thought I'd just be able to add:

`0.0.0.0       localhost`

to my `hosts` file but that doesn't seem to work. For instance, I have a debugger running on `http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858`. Works fine. But when I add the above line to my hosts file and try to access `http://0.0.0.0:8080/debug?port=5858` I get:

`Error 108 (net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID): Unknown error.`

Node-inspector is a good example:

```
$ node-inspector                                                      
   info  - socket.io started                                          
visit http://0.0.0.0:8080/debug?port=5858 to start debugging
```

Do I just need to manually edit that IP to be equal to localhost when copy/pasting? Or is this a weird difference between Linux and Windows?

How do I get `0.0.0.0` to be equivalent to `localhost` when browsing urls in Windows 7? Chrome is my 'default' browser.

Comment: refer to rfc1122 for details on your question: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1122

Comment: "many node programs expect 0.0.0.0 to be equal to 127.0.0.1" ... What? This... I have no words.

Comment: also this: http://serverfault.com/a/78058

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams well they expect 0.0.0.0 to be there as opposed to nothing -- maybe I mis-stated it

Comment: Binding to 0.0.0.0 allows incoming connections from *any* interface; making it localhost only will break so very much.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Why not tell node-inspector et alia to bind to 127.0.0.1 instead?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams because I'd have to do that for every node module that listens on a url

Comment: So... what exactly is the issue here? That you don't want these services exposed to everybody, or that you want to be able to put `0.0.0.0` in your browser's location bar?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I updated the title, should clear it up

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, what's happening here is that node is binding to `0.0.0.0` - netspeak for "All interfaces". This includes localhost, any real interfaces you have, and any virtual interfaces you have. It in and of itself generally does not point to an individual interface. (Technically, it points to "This host on this network", but that's ambiguous at best because "this network" is not defined. So `0.0.0.0` is usually understood to point represent the local computer's IP on *every* network)

Do you need to manually edit that IP when copy/pasting? Yes. If Linux or a specific browser on linux happens to silently correct it to `127.0.0.1`... awesome. But as you've found out, that's not a universal thing.

Comment: Blech, I figured the answer was "that's just windows" but was hoping for better.

Comment: `http://0.0.0.0:8080/debug?port=5858` converted to `http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858` will work then...

Comment: It will, but it's a pain to do it everywhere everytime.

Comment: FiascoLabs If you read the original question, it does. @jcollum I would actually use that same sentiment towards linux here - It's supporting obscure, ambiguous usecases which only serve to limit interoperability, and I would further blame node.js for not properly cleaning up the URL before printing it out.

Comment: See KB970313 "The Default Gateway may have been set to 0.0.0.0 on a Windows Vista-based or later OS running Apple’s Bonjour service" https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/970313

Comment: How does this answer the question "how do I get 0.0.0.0 to resolve to localhost"?

Comment: It doesn't, because the answer is "You can't." Instead, I try to explain the meaning of `0.0.0.0` so that OP might better understand _why_ it doesn't work, and clarify that you have to replace it with a real IP address if you want a link that will work properly regardless of browser/operating system.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a browser extension to redirect the page when it detects it's on a 0.0.0.0 url. I used the redirector extension for chrome with these settings:

```
Description: 0.0.0.0 to localhost
Example URL: http://0.0.0.0:4000/webpack-dev-server/
Include pattern: ([a-zA-Z]*)://0.0.0.0:(\d*)/(.*)
Redirect to: $1://localhost:$2/$3
Pattern type: Regular Expression
Example result: http://localhost:4000/webpack-dev-server/
```